zsh error in money order function.How I solve?
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define I 27
#define IR 25
#define File "test.txt"

struct customer
{
    long long identity;
    char iban[I];
    int money;
};

void filesave(struct customer cus)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(File,"a");
    if (file==NULL)
    {
        printf("the file did not open properly.");
    }

    fprintf(file,"%lld %s %d \n",cus.identity,cus.iban,cus.money);

    fclose(file);
}

int identitycontrol(long long identity)
{
     int a=0,bas;
    long long i=1;
    while (a<11)
    {
        bas=(identity/i)%10;
        if (bas<0 || bas>9)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
        i*=10;
        a++;
    }
    if (identity / i > 0 && identity>0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int ibancontrol(char iban[I])
{
     if(!isalpha(iban[0]) || !isalpha(iban[1]))
     return 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < I; i++)
    {
        if (iban[i]<48 || iban[i]>57)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        
    }
    return 1;
}

int moneycontrol(int money)
{
    if (money>0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int transfermoneycontrol(int b, int m)
{
    if(b>=m)
        return 1;
     else
        return 0;
}

int moneyorder(char account1[I],char account2[I],int transfermoney)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(File,"r");
    struct customer cus[100];
    char temp[100];
    int y=0,s=0,k;
    while ( fgets(temp,100, file) != NULL )
    {
            sscanf(temp,"%lld %s %d",&cus[s].identity,cus[s].iban,&cus[s].money);
    

        if(strcmp(cus[s].iban,account1)==0)
        {
                cus[s].money -=transfermoney;  
                y++;

        }
        if(strcmp(cus[s].iban,account2)==0)
        {
            cus[s].money +=transfermoney;
            y++;
        }
        s++;
    }    
     for(int z=0;z<s;z++)
    {
        printf("\nGuncel bilgiler:\n");
        printf("%d: %s  %lld  %d \n",z+1,cus[z].iban,cus[z].identity,cus[z].money);
    }
    
    fclose(file);

    

    if (y != 2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    file = fopen(File, "w");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("the file did not open properly.");
        return 0;
    }
    
    for (int s = 0; s < IR; s++)
    {
        fprintf(file, "%lld %d %s ", cus[s].identity, cus[s].money, cus[s].iban);
        if (s !=IR-1)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        
    }

    return  1;
}

int main()
{
    int choice=0,control=0;
    struct customer cus;
    char account1[I],account2[I];
    int transfermoney;
   
    
    while (1)
    { 

    printf("-----Menü-----\n");
    printf("1:Entry\n");
    printf("2:Transfer\n");
    printf("3:Exit\n");

    printf("What is your choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice); 
    fflush(stdin);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        while (1)
        {   
                printf("Please enter your identity: ");
                scanf("%lld",&cus.identity);
                fflush(stdin);
                if (identitycontrol(cus.identity)==1)
                {
                    
                break;
                }   
        }
        while (1)
        {
                printf("Please enter your iban: ");
                scanf("%s",cus.iban);
                //fgets(cus.iban,I,stdin);
                //cus.iban[strlen(cus.iban)-1]='\0';                
                fflush(stdin);
                if (ibancontrol(cus.iban)==1)
                {
                    
                    break;
                }
        }
        while (1)
        {
                printf("Please enter your money: ");

                scanf("%d",&cus.money);
                fflush(stdin);
                if (moneycontrol(cus.money)==1)
                {
                    break;
                }    
        }     
                filesave(cus);
        break;
        case 2 :
        while (1)
        {
                printf("Please enter the main account we will send money to: ");
                //fgets(account1,I,stdin);
                scanf("%s",account1);
                fflush(stdin);
                if (ibancontrol(account1)==1)
                { 
                    
                    break;
                }       
        }
        while (1)
        {
                printf("Please enter the account from which you will receive money.: ");
                //fgets(account2,I,stdin);
                scanf("%s",account2);
               fflush(stdin);
                if (ibancontrol(account2)==1)
                { 
                    break;
                }  
        }        
        while (1)
        {
                printf("Please enter your transfer money: ");
                scanf("%d",&transfermoney);
                fflush(stdin);
                if (moneycontrol(transfermoney)==1)
                {
                    break;
                }          
        }
                int a=moneyorder(account1,account2,transfermoney);
            if (a==1)
            {
                printf("Money order sucsessful.");
            }
            else if (a==0)
            {
                printf("Money order unsucsessful.");
            }
            


            
            break;
        case 3:
                exit(2);
        break;
    default:
                printf("Wrong choice!!\n");
        break;
    }
   
}
 return 0;



}

I get a zsh trace trap error when I come to the money order function, how can I solve it?
The transfer function does not receive the exact values ​​in the file.I don't understand why?
I'ts like okey but not working.I think strtod function maybe but ı don't know.When I write to the file, I put a space at the end, so strtod should logically work, but it doesn't.

fflush(stdin); is undefined behavior. Check the return values of fopen(), strtok(), and scanf().

Apparently IBANs can have up to 34 characters... make sure you do not have embedded spaces.

Morpen, When the file does not open properly, exit the code rather than continue with fprintf(file,"%lld %s %d \n",cus.identity,cus.iban,cus.money);

#define I 27 --> #define I 100  (as big as temp)
